# MapBox geojson data not displaying with certain "Styles"

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I can get my data from a geojson file in my site's directory to display my data on default Mapbox style (v9 dark etc...) But for some reason it just shows no data on my custom styled maps (only certain ones)...

Confused.

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title>Major Civil War Battles</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
 <style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2dc4b2;
}

#console {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: white;
}   

</style>     
      
      
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div id='map'></div>

      <div id='console'>
  <h1>Major Battles of The Civil War (1861-1865)</h1>
  <p></p>
 
          <div class='session' id='sliderbar'>
  <h2>Year: <label id='active-year'>1861</label></h2>
  <input id='slider' class='row' type='range' min='1861' max='1865' step='1' value='1861' />
          </div>
    
      </div>
      
      
</body>
    
    
<script>  
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZzlramN2Mzh0c3Uyd252cWxzYnF3c2UifQ.5lpaHuwMqJ5EsTARqW5kHg';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container element id
    //mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9
    //mapbox://styles/cgroth/cjgl5x6c400002qnkl94ab1yc
  style: 'mapbox://styles/cgroth/cjgl5x6c400002qnkl94ab1yc',
    center: [-77.04, 38.907],
    zoom: 5
});
    
    
 map.on('load', function() {
    map.addLayer({
      id: 'battledata',
      type: 'circle',
      source: {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: './CWGG.geojson' // replace this with the url of your own geojson
      },
      paint: {
        'circle-radius': [
          'interpolate',
          ['linear'],
          ['number', ['get', 'TotalCasualties']],
          1, 2,
          51000, 40
        ],
        'circle-color':'#AA5E79',
        'circle-opacity': 0.8
      }
    }, 'admin-2-boundaries-dispute');
  document.getElementById('slider').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var year = parseInt(e.target.value);
  // update the map
  map.setFilter('battledata', ['==', ['number', ['get', 'Year']], year]);

  // update text in the UI
  document.getElementById('active-year').innerText = year
});   
     
  });
    
</script>
```

If I run the exact same code with a default Mapbox "Style" my data displays perfectly. I insert my style code and nothing appears.

Here are the console errors when I try to run the HTML:

```html
rror: Layer with id "admin-2-boundaries-dispute" does not exist on this map.
    at r.addLayer (style.js:542)
    at e.addLayer (map.js:1125)
    at e.<anonymous> (AA_WorkingCW.html:85)
    at e.Evented.fire (evented.js:93)
    at r.Evented.fire (evented.js:103)
    at r._load (style.js:226)
    at style.js:164
    at XMLHttpRequest.r.onload (ajax.js:76)
Evented.fire @ evented.js:109
favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/19/25.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/20/24.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
b.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/19/26.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/20/26.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
5evented.js:109 Error: The layer 'battledata' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be filtered.
    at r.setFilter (style.js:681)
    at e.setFilter (map.js:1185)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (AA_WorkingCW.html:107)
Evented.fire @ evented.js:109
ajax.js:106 GET https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/20/24.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ 404 (Not Found)
exports.getArrayBuffer @ ajax.js:106
exports.getImage @ ajax.js:121
r.loadTile @ raster_dem_tile_source.js:37
t._loadTile @ source_cache.js:144
t._addTile @ source_cache.js:584
t._updateRetainedTiles @ source_cache.js:489
t.update @ source_cache.js:435
r._updateSources @ style.js:943
e._render @ map.js:1499
(anonymous) @ map.js:1567
requestAnimationFrame (async)
frame @ browser.js:30
e._rerender @ map.js:1565
e._update @ map.js:1450
Evented.fire @ evented.js:93
e.resize @ map.js:408
e._onWindowResize @ map.js:1578
ajax.js:106 GET https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/20/26.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ 404 (Not Found)
exports.getArrayBuffer @ ajax.js:106
exports.getImage @ ajax.js:121
r.loadTile @ raster_dem_tile_source.js:37
t._loadTile @ source_cache.js:144
t._addTile @ source_cache.js:584
t._updateRetainedTiles @ source_cache.js:489
t.update @ source_cache.js:435
r._updateSources @ style.js:943
e._render @ map.js:1499
(anonymous) @ map.js:1567
requestAnimationFrame (async)
frame @ browser.js:30
e._rerender @ map.js:1565
e._update @ map.js:1450
Evented.fire @ evented.js:93
e.resize @ map.js:408
e._onWindowResize @ map.js:1578
ajax.js:106 GET https://b.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/21/26.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ 404 (Not Found)
exports.getArrayBuffer @ ajax.js:106
exports.getImage @ ajax.js:121
r.loadTile @ raster_dem_tile_source.js:37
t._loadTile @ source_cache.js:144
t._addTile @ source_cache.js:584
t._updateRetainedTiles @ source_cache.js:489
t.update @ source_cache.js:435
r._updateSources @ style.js:943
e._render @ map.js:1499
(anonymous) @ map.js:1567
requestAnimationFrame (async)
frame @ browser.js:30
e._rerender @ map.js:1565
e._update @ map.js:1450
Evented.fire @ evented.js:93
e.resize @ map.js:408
e._onWindowResize @ map.js:1578
ajax.js:106 GET https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/21/25.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ 404 (Not Found)
exports.getArrayBuffer @ ajax.js:106
exports.getImage @ ajax.js:121
r.loadTile @ raster_dem_tile_source.js:37
t._loadTile @ source_cache.js:144
t._addTile @ source_cache.js:584
t._updateRetainedTiles @ source_cache.js:489
t.update @ source_cache.js:435
r._updateSources @ style.js:943
e._render @ map.js:1499
(anonymous) @ map.js:1567
requestAnimationFrame (async)
frame @ browser.js:30
e._rerender @ map.js:1565
e._update @ map.js:1450
Evented.fire @ evented.js:93
e.resize @ map.js:408
e._onWindowResize @ map.js:1578
ajax.js:106 GET https://b.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/6/21/24.webp?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2dyb3RoIiwiYSI6ImNqZ2w4bWY5dTFueG0zM2w0dTNkazI1aWEifQ.55SWFVBYzs08EqJHAa3AsQ 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 2):

> `Layer with id "admin-2-boundaries-dispute" does not exist on this map.`

This error is telling you that you're trying to insert your new layer before a layer which doesn't exist. Presumably it exists in the dark layer, but not in your custom layer. Mapbox-GL-JS recently changed so that inserting a layer before a non-existent layer fails completely - it does not get added.

Comment: I discovered as much shortly after posting this. This error is occurring because I accidentally deleted the "admin-X-boundaries-dispute" layers. Any ideas on how to get them back into my highly customized style without completely starting over?

Comment: Not really. But that would be a new question in any case. If this answer was correct, please mark it as accepted.